# Handle exception in HttpResponse asp .net

Tags: c#, .net, api, http, exception

I'm in a debate with myself on how to handle exceptions when calling a rest-API endpoint. I'm deserializing the content directly from a stream to avoid the allocation of a string. The problem that arises is if the server returns an internal server error (500) with some information in the content my deserialization fails because of the JSON and if I call `responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` I lose the information in the content.

```
var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

using (var stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
   return _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);
}
```

How do I handle the exception details that might exist in the Content?

Comment: Maybe by checking if `responseMessage.StatusCode == 200`

Comment: I could do that, but if it isnt? Do i deserilaze to object and throw my own exception with details from content or return null and log? Im not sure..

Comment: if not 200, you should read as string actually, because we don't know what kind of format the content has. I would check if the exception will have the content when let to be raised to the caller, and if not, just ReadToEnd() and throw a custom exception with the message containing the content, and having the web exception  as inner exception.

Answer (score 0):

[@Oguz Ozgul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5497207/oguz-ozgul) something like this?

```
if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using (var stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        return _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);
    }
}
else
{
    var result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    throw new HttpRequestException(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be situations as well when the server does not return anything at all rather than you would face with one of the following exception:

- `ArgumentException` / `ArgumentNullException` / `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

  - Occurs:

    - When the provided string can't be parsed as an URI
    - When the `Timeout` / `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` setter receives too small / too big input
  - Handling:

    - Prevention

      - Use `Uri.TryCreate` to parse string
      - Use the strongly typed overloads
      - Should NOT catch it, should be prevented
- `WebException`

  - Occurs:

    - When the underlying network fails for some reason (see [status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexceptionstatus?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more details)
  - Handling:

    - Detection

      - Mostly it is wrapped inside an `HttpRequestException`
    - Mitigation

      - Call the [CancelPendingRequests](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/33/gotchas-with-httpclients-cancelpendingrequests-and-timeout-in-net)
- `InvalidOperationException`

  - Occurs:

    - When the `BaseAddress` setter is called after a request has been sent out
    - When the `Timeout` setter is called after a request has been sent out
    - When the `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` setter is called after a request has been sent out
    - When an operation has already started and re-sending was requested
  - Handling:

    - Prevention

      - Try to avoid to set "global" properties
    - Detection

      - It can be thrown individually or inside an `WebException`
    - Mitigation

      - Call the [CancelPendingRequests](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/33/gotchas-with-httpclients-cancelpendingrequests-and-timeout-in-net)
- `HttpException`

  - Occurs:

    - ASP.NET can throw this exception
  - Handling:

    - Detection

      - Catch it [application level](https://gist.github.com/bmcdavid/152cb2f1fd26e1796430f9c4a7a263a2) at Application_Error
      - Please bear in mind that the [WebEventCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.management.webeventcodes?view=netframework-4.7.2)'s Message is localised
- `TaskCanceledException`

  - Occurs:

    - When the request has been cancelled
    - When the request has been timed out
  - Handling:

    - Prevention

      - Make your timeouts environment specific
    - Detection

      - Do NOT catch `TimeoutException`
      - The [recommended approach](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/)
    - Mitigation

      - Use retry with exponential back-off if the request is idempotent
- `HttpRequestException`

  - Occurs:

    - Most of the above mentioned exceptions are wrapped inside a HRE
    - When calling the `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` and the status code is different than 2xx
  - Handling:

    - Prevention

      - Do NOT call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`
      - Check the status codes explicitly
    - Detection

      - Definitely should be catched and `InnerException` should be examined
      - Please be aware of the [StatusCode limitations](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23648)
- `SocketException`

  - Occurs:

    - When a new request is asked from a disposed httpClient
    - When connection opens are called too frequently (exhausting the pool)
  - Handling:

    - Prevention

      - Do not create a new httpClient for each request
      - Use it as [intended](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/)
      - Use `HttpClientFactory`
    - Detection

      - Measure and resize the pool size if it is reasonable
      - Check [SocketErrorCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketerror?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- `IOException`

  - Occurs:

    - When the response could not be read from the underlying network stream
    - When wrong TLS version is used
  - Handling:

    - Prevention

      - Use [proper TLS](https://60secondtutorial.com/2015/10/25/system-io-ioexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/) version
    - Detection

      - Most of the time they are encapsulated in this way:
      - `HttpRequestException` > `WebException` > `IOException` > `SocketException`